# Como colocar dois controllers em uma página sem que um interfira o outro

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

estou fazendo alguns formulários com Angular e em alguns dos casos preciso que a pessoa coloque alguma informação para salvar a chave estrangeira, exemplo básico:

Vamos supor a venda de um produto e a tabela da nota fiscal no banco de dados pede os id's do vendedor, produto e cliente.

Para isso coloquei um datalist para facilitar ao usuário e ele poder selecionar exatamente aquilo que ele quer. E para listar todos os dados disponíveis para o usuário selecionar estou usando uma diretiva do Angular chamado ng-repeat sendo assim preciso adicionar um controller, problema é quando eu preciso de outro controller para listar no outro datalist porém o primeiro controller já controla todo o resto da aplicação e todos os datalist que eu adicionar listam a mesma coisa que o primeiro.

```
<div ng-controller="ClientesCtrl as clCtrl">
        <section >
            <form name="some">
              <label> Cliente
           <input type="text" list="dataList">
              </label>
              <datalist id="dataList">
                <option ng-repeat="clientesSave in clCtrl.clientesSaves" value="{{clientesSave.id_cliente}}" ng-model="odCtrl.equipSave.id_cliente">{{clientesSave.nome}}</option>
              </datalist>
              </form>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="EquipCtrl as eqCtrl">
          <section ng-controller="EquipCtrl as eqCtrl">
                <form name="some">
                  <label> Tipo de Equipamento
               <input type="text" list="dataList" placeholder="selecione">
                  </label>
                  <datalist id="dataList">
                    <option ng-repeat="equipSave in eqCtrl.equipSaves" value="{{equipSave.id_tipo}}" ng-model="odCtrl.equipSave.id_tipo">{{equipSave.nome_equip}}</option>
                  </datalist>
                  </form>
              </section>
            </div>
```

Tentei fazer um component mas dá na mesma, então pensei em duas possíveis soluções mas não sei se é boa prática, primeiro seria eu adicionar as rotas do back no mesmo controller, então seria dois ou mais comandos get por controller só para me dar informações que eu quero de outra tabela, ou então no próprio back eu já faço as buscas que preciso, coloco todas as informações necessárias em uma rota e adiciono essa rota no controller responsável por tal formulário.

Ou então tem alguma forma de eu isolar o primeiro controller para não afetar os demais?

Comment: Talvez esse artigo lhe ajude https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-trabalhando-com-dois-controllers-numa-mesma-view-74921 Tive um problema parecido e meu problema estava no código mal organizado, espero que ajude.